# Are the alien creatures able to inhabit androids?

Tags: dark-matter

It appears that the alien 'goo' creatures are able to inhabit humans and even Two/Portia/Rebecca whom is biologically enhanced with nanites. The question is, is there any evidence that the aliens can inhabit androids?